# Построить список из массива

Tags: php, html, mysql

При помощи Nestable Lists получил из списка на HTML сериализованную строку:

```
[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16,"children":[{"id":17,"children":[{"id":18},{"id":19},{"id":20}]}]}]},{"id":21}]
```

Как теперь мне из нее снова построить список на HTML:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable_list_1">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="13">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 13</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="14">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 14</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="15">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 15</div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="16">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 16</div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="17">
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 17</div>
                            <ol class="dd-list">
                                <li class="dd-item" data-id="18">
                                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 18</div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dd-item" data-id="19">
                                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 19</div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dd-item" data-id="20">
                                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 20</div>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="21">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 21</div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: так а язык какой нужно использовать?

Comment: Что то вы слишком много тегов написали. какое это имеет отношение к mysql, на каком языке вы хотите решить эту задачу. И кстати, что вы сами пробовали сделать для решения данной задачи, приведите пример кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable_list_1">
<ol class="dd-list">
    <?
        $query_cat_sort = mysql_query("SELECT `cat_sort` FROM `param`",$db);
        $cat_sort_string = mysql_fetch_row($query_cat_sort, 0);
        $cat_sort_array = json_decode($cat_sort_string['cat_sort'], true);

        function ListBuilding($sort_array){
            foreach($sort_array as $sort_item){
                echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$sort_item['id'].'">
                            <div class="dd-handle">'.$sort_item['id'].'</div>';
                if(isset($sort_item['children'])){
                    echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
                    ListBuilding($sort_item['children']);
                    echo '</ol>';
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }

        ListBuilding($cat_sort_array);
    ?>
</ol>
```

Со своей базой MySQL работаю таким образом:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable_list_1">
<ol class="dd-list">
    <?
        $query_cat_sort = mysql_query("SELECT `cat_sort` FROM `param`",$db);
        $cat_sort_string = mysql_fetch_row($query_cat_sort, 0);
        $cat_sort_array = json_decode($cat_sort_string['cat_sort'], true);

        function ListBuilding($sort_array){
            foreach($sort_array as $sort_item){
                $query_get_title = mysql_query("SELECT `title` FROM `cat2` WHERE `id`=".$sort_item['id']);
                $get_title = mysql_fetch_row($query_get_title, 0);
                echo '<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.$sort_item['id'].'">
                            <div class="dd-handle">'.$get_title['title'].'</div>';
                if(isset($sort_item['children'])){
                    echo '<ol class="dd-list">';
                    ListBuilding($sort_item['children']);
                    echo '</ol>';
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }

        ListBuilding($cat_sort_array);
    ?>
</ol>
```

Но неужели нет более простого и компактного решения? Может какие-нибудь стандартные функции PHP или HTML5? JavaScript в конце концов?