# Построить многоуровневый список из многоуровневого объекта

Tags: javascript, html

Есть в наличии такой пример js-объекта:

```js
let tree = {
    label: 'Beverages',
    children: [
        {label: 'Water'},
        {label: 'Coffee'},
        {
            label: 'Tea',
            children: [
                {label: 'Black Tea'},
                {label: 'White Tea'},
                {
                    label: 'Green Tea',
                    children: [
                        {label: 'Sencha'},
                        {label: 'Gyokuro'},
                        {label: 'Matcha'},
                        {label: 'Pi Lo Chun'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

из которого необходимо динамически построить список вида:

```html
<div id="myTree">
    <ul class="tree-view">
      <li><span class="box">Beverages</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li>Water</li>
          <li>Coffee</li>
          <li><span class="box">Tea</span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li>Black Tea</li>
              <li>White Tea</li>
              <li><span class="box">Green Tea</span>
                <ul class="nested">
                  <li>Sencha</li>
                  <li>Gyokuro</li>
                  <li>Matcha</li>
                  <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>  
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

желательно одной функцией и без глобальных переменных. Заранее спасибо.

UPD. Что пытался делать я:

```js
function drawTree(obj, el) {
  if (obj.children) {
    const list = document.createElement('ul');
    //if(el.tagName == 'DIV') list.className = 'tree-view';
    el.appendChild(list);
    Object.keys(obj.children).forEach(key => {
      const dir = obj.children[key];
      let text;
      const list_el = document.createElement('li');
      if(key == 0) {
        text = document.createElement('span');
        text.className = 'box';
        text.innerHTML = (dir.label);
      }
      else {
        text = document.createTextNode(dir.label);
      }
      list_el.appendChild(text);
      list.appendChild(list_el);

      drawTree(dir, list_el);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Желательно добавить код, в котором вы пытались решить данную задачу.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Построить список из массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489476/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Ваш код работает =)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, добавил попытки решить. Посмотрел пост. Мне нужно на JS, без php.

Comment: @Skywave, почти. Я с классами запутался. Не могу понять как выставить их динамически. Классы указаны в html-коде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так достаточно лаконично, через рекурсию и шаблоны строк:

```js
let buildTree = node => `<li>${node.children ? `

  <span class="box">${node.label}</span>
  <ul class="nested">${node.children.map(buildTree).join('')}</ul>
  
` : node.label}</li>`;


let tree = {
    label: 'Beverages',
    children: [
        {label: 'Water'},
        {label: 'Coffee'},
        {label: 'Tea',
         children: [
                {label: 'Black Tea'},
                {label: 'White Tea'},
                {label: 'Green Tea',
                 children: [
                        {label: 'Sencha'},
                        {label: 'Gyokuro'},
                        {label: 'Matcha'},
                        {label: 'Pi Lo Chun'}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

document.querySelector('.tree-view').innerHTML = buildTree(tree);
```

```html
<div id="myTree"><ul class="tree-view"></ul></div>
```

Comment: спасибо. Только начал переходить с ES5 на 6 и о шаблонных строках не сразу подумал... Да и вряд ли я бы так быстро сообразил, спасибо Вам большое.

Comment: @Евгений не за что, это не супер принципиально, могла бы быть обычная конкатенация, просто так меньше кода

Comment: Как я понял, при рендере недостающие ul'лы добавились? Дело не только в строках, не мог подумать, что решение вложится в 10 строк.

Comment: @Евгений я не понял Ваш вопрос

Comment: Я понял от куда там ul'лы, простите, что запутал, не сразу заметил. Просто я использую первый Ваш вариант, его читать удобней, а смотрю на вариант новый, и не сразу проследил логику. В любом случае, спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 1):

В целом вы были на верном пути - здесь действительно всё решается простой рекурсией:

```js
const tree = {
    label: "Beverages",
    children: [{ label: "Water" },
    { label: "Coffee" },
    {
        label: "Tea",
        children: [{ label: "Black Tea" },
        { label: "White Tea" },
        {
            label: "Green Tea",
            children: [{ label: "Sencha" },
            { label: "Gyokuro" },
            { label: "Matcha" },
            { label: "Pi Lo Chun" }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
};

function drawTree(obj, el) {
    const li = document.createElement("li")
    li.innerHTML = `<span class="box">${obj.label}</span>`
    el.appendChild(li)

    if (!obj.children) {
        return
    }

    const ul = document.createElement("ul")
    ul.className = "nested"
    li.appendChild(ul)
    obj.children.forEach(c => {
        drawTree(c, ul)
    })
}

drawTree(tree, document.getElementById("list"))
```

```html
<div id="myTree">
    <ul id="list" class="tree-view"></ul>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, чтоб не усложнять функцию, проще корневой `ul` создавать не в ней. Может создать его заранее и найти по селектору (как в примере), можете создать динамически в другой функции.
Это не обязательно, но это избавит вас от дополнительного условия, которое будет отрабатывать в холостую при отрисовке каждого элемента.

Удачи!

Comment: не подумайте, что я хочу, чтобы всё сделали за меня, но вывести список у меня кое-как получилось - беда в правильном расположении "подсписков" и классов.

Comment: @Евгений я внёс соответствующие правки в код - теперь результирующий html идентичен тому, что у вас в вопросе. Удачи!)

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись. Правда классы немного не туда попали, но решение было куда проще. Вам тоже удачи.

Answer (score 1):

Немного поправил ваш код.

Вместо проверки на `DIV` добавил новый параметр функции `root`. При первом вызове явно говорим, что он `true`.

```
function drawTree(obj, el, root) {
  if (obj.children) {
    const list = document.createElement('ul');
    if(root) list.className = 'tree-view';
    else list.className = 'nested';
    el.appendChild(list);
    Object.keys(obj.children).forEach(key => {
      const dir = obj.children[key];
      let text;
      const list_el = document.createElement('li');
      if(key == 0) {
        text = document.createElement('span');
        text.className = 'box';
        text.innerHTML = (dir.label);
      }
      else {
        text = document.createTextNode(dir.label);
      }
      list_el.appendChild(text);
      list.appendChild(list_el);

      drawTree(dir, list_el);
    });
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/advjrc2h/15/

Comment: расположение вложенных списков и классов немного не то. Сейчас пытаюсь заставить Ваш код работать так как нужно.